# Como puedo extraer los datos de un jsonArray que dentro de ella tiene otro Array? - Android Studio

Tags: android, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

en mi clase php estoy generando el siguiente array (corrijanme si esta mal):

```
http_response_code(200);
$dato = $this->clase_cliente->obtenerDatos($this->correo_electronico);
$jsonDatosUsuario['DatosUsuario'][] = array('nombre'=> $dato['nombre'], 'apellido'=> $dato['apellido'], 'correo_electronico'=> $dato['correo_electronico'], 'foto_perfil'=> $dato['foto_perfil']);
$jsonResponse['response'][] = array('TagResponse' => 'DatosObtenidos', 'Datos' => $jsonDatosUsuario);
echo(json_encode($jsonResponse));
```

Y como resultado obtengo el siguiente JsonArray:

```
{"response":
           [{"TagResponse":"DatosObtenidos",
                   "Datos":{"DatosUsuario":[{"nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Lopez","correo_electronico":"juanlopez@gmail.com","foto_perfil":null}]}}]}
```

Y en mi clase java tengo lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    if(response != null){
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
            object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            if(object.getString("TagResponse").equals("DatosObtenidos")){
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Datos");
                object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }
            }else{

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            errorVolley.errorListener("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Lo que trato de hacer es de que una vez recibido el Json se analize el `TagResponse`, si el `TagResponse` tiene un valor de `DatosObtenidos` quiere decir que los datos del usuario se obtuvieron correctamente y que puedo proseguir a obtener los datos que se encuentran dentro del Json: `DatosUsuario`, en mi clase java solo logre verificar si el `TagResponse` es igual a `DatosObtenidos` luego despues de eso ya no se como puedo acceder a leer y extraer los datos del usuario, alguien porfavor que me ayude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente la respuesta que estas resiviendo desde el Servidor es en formato `JSONObject`

Estructura de un JSON:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el código para acceder a la información del usuario:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("response");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                        if (jsonObject.getString("TagResponse").equals("DatosObtenidos")) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Datos");
                            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("DatosUsuario");

                            // Recorrer los datos del usuario
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                                String nombre = object.getString("nombre");
                                String apellido = object.getString("apellido");
                                String correo = object.getString("correo_electronico");
                                String foto_perfil = object.getString("foto_perfil");

                                Log.d("Data", "Nombre = " + nombre + " Apellido = " + apellido + " Correo= " + correo + " Foto= " + foto_perfil);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("Exception", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //Some Code
    }
});

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Segun la imagen que pusiste, el Json que estoy devolviendo esta mal estructurado?

Comment: No me refería a que esta mal estructurado, si no que de acuerdo al tipo de respuesta JSON vas a recuperar la informacion [Tipos de respuesta](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request)